# Nested mapping with 2d arrays: I need the index of my outer arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm making a puzzle game that relies on elements being placed in grids and evaluating the values at certain x,y locations. My data is stored in 2d arrays, so regular maps don't work that well. As a result, I made this helper function to map over every single cell in a 2d array.

```
// makes transformations on the cell level in a 2d array
export const twoDMap = (twoDimensionalArray, mapFunction) => {
  return twoDimensionalArray.map((row, y) => {
    return row.map(mapFunction);
  })
}
```

This works fine most of the time, *except* when I need to use the x,y indexes of a cell in my 2d map. In the test case below, I can't seem to access the y value of the cells. (I got rid of the ES6 syntax so it'll run in the console)

```
var testArray = [[true, "random-string", 3],
                 ["potato", false, 4],
                 [null, 4, 5]];

function twoDMap(twoDimensionalArray, mapFunction) {
 return twoDimensionalArray.map(function (row, y) {
   return row.map(mapFunction);
 })
}

function logCells(cells)  {
  twoDMap(cells ,function(cell, x) {
    console.log(cell, "location: ", x);
    // console.log(cell, "location: ", x, y); //throws an error
  })
}

logCells(testArray);
```

I'm pretty sure I need to make some kind of change to `twoDMap`, and it's probably quite minor, but I've been on this problem for hours and still can't get it to work. When I write it out manually (using regular nested maps instead of `twoDMap` ), it works fine, but it's overly verbose and I'd like to avoid it considering that it's a common pattern in this project. This is the common suggestion that I keep finding whenever I google this problem, but it's not a viable solution given how much nesting I need to do for this project.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to modify `twoDMap` or the callbacks that are sent into it, so that my callbacks can access the x *and* y indexes of the 2d array sent to `twoDMap`.

Comment: `row.map`, you could alter this to accept the `y` as another param, and then pass this to the callback so that mapFunction callback get's the Y,.. But I must say all this looks very convoluted to access a 2d array.

Comment: @Keith how would you alter `row.map`? I've tried different things and nothing's given me the result I was looking for so far. In some cases it's super easy to access the arrays ( `array[y][x]` ), but in this case the 2d arrays are of variable shapes and sizes (flattening them won't yield consistent results).

Comment: Are you able to post a working snippet?

Comment: @Keith I added a self-contained snippet that can be run in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the 'y' is out of scope to the current function, so it can't 'see' the value. For this reason you need to work out how to make it available to the second function. The two approaches I see:

- Make second function's map an inner operation, within `twoDimensionalArray.map(function (row, y)`
- Find a way to pass 'y' to the second function

For the first approach:

```
var testArray = [[true, "random-string", 3],
                 ["potato", false, 4],
                 [null, 4, 5]];

function twoDMap(twoDimensionalArray) {
 return twoDimensionalArray.map(function (row, y) {
   return row.map(function (row, x) {
     console.log(cell, "location: ", x, y);
   }
 })
}    

twoDMap(testArray);
```

Below takes the second approach, using the `bind()` function:

```
var testArray = [[true, "random-string", 3],
                 ["potato", false, 4],
                 [null, 4, 5]];

function twoDMap(twoDimensionalArray, mapFunction) {
 return twoDimensionalArray.map(function (row, y) {
   return row.map(mapFunction.bind(this, y);
 })
}

function logCells(cells)  {
  twoDMap(cells , function(y, cell, x) {    
    console.log(cell, "location: ", x, y);
  })
}

logCells(testArray);
```

When binding a values to a function always remember the first parameter should correspond to how you wish to define `this` and then the subsequent parameters are provided as initial parameters to the function you are calling.

I should add that sometimes using the traditional `for` loops makes for more manageable code, and sometimes benefit from better performance. An alternative, using for loops:

```
var testArray = [[true, "random-string", 3],
                 ["potato", false, 4],
                 [null, 4, 5]];

function twoDMap(twoDimensionalArray) {
  for (var y=0; y<twoDimensionalArray.length; y++) {
     for (var x=0; x<twoDimensionalArray[y].length; x++) {
        console.log(twoDimensionalArray[y][x], "location: ", x, y);
     }
  }
}

twoDMap(testArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, re-implementing the inner map as a `for` loop and then manually passing the coordinates to the transforming callback does the trick. The callback in `array.map` has to follow a set format for its arguments ( `callback(element, index, array)`) but by having the callback act alone in a `for` loop, that restriction is lifted.

```
var testArray = [[true, "random-string", 3],
                 ["potato", false, 4],
                 [null, 4, 5]];

function twoDMap(twoDimensionalArray, transform) {
 return twoDimensionalArray.map(function (row, y) {
   var mapped = [];
   for (var x = 0; x < row.length; x++)
     mapped.push(transform(row[x], x, y));
   return mapped;
 })
}

twoDMap(testArray, function(cell, x, y) {
  console.log(cell, x, y);
})
```

if someone knows *why* the first attempt with the nested map didn't work, I'd be very curious to learn about that. I still don't know why it didn't have access to the scope that contained the `y`...